# mat-tab label is moving when it's selected for a short while. how to solve this issue

Tags: angular

```
.mat-tab-group {
  margin: 10px;
}

.mat-tab-label-active {
  width: 50px;
  background: silver;
  color: darkblue;
  font-weight: bold;
  border-top-right-radius: 5px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  opacity: 1 !important;
  text-align: center;
  animation: none;
}

.mat-tab-label {
  text-align: center;
  width: 50px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  background: silver;
  color: darkblue;
  font-weight: bold;
  border-top-right-radius: 10px;
  border-top-left-radius: 10px;
}
```

I'm trying to set text width about 50px for active and not active but still the label is moving is there any other attributes

Comment: Can you please provide a stackblitz or codepen demo?

Comment: https://angular-6bk3cn.stackblitz.io

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6bk3cn

Answer (score 1):

just add this line in your `src/styles.css` file:

```
@import '~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/deeppurple-amber.css';
```